# Does a CommCare app copy from the latest saved state or the latest deploy?

Tags: commcare

If I copy a CommCare application from one project space to another, will the copy of the app represent the latest *saved* state of the original application or the latest *deployed* state of the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be the latest saved state. If you want to copy the latest deployed state then you would need to 'revert' to that build before copying.

To keep the latest saved state you could:

1. create a build (let's call it 'Build Latest')
2. revert to the build you want to copy
3. copy the app to the new project space
4. revert back to 'Build Latest' to restore your app to it's original state